# How to extend native DOM elements using "is"?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-component

I am trying to using the custom elements spec to [extend native DOM elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) using the "is" attribute, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. I am using Google Canary so I am able to create custom elements, but no effect in extending.

In my sample, I am trying to add a caption to the native img tag:

```
<img is="super-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" 
  caption="This is my custom caption!" />

<script>
  document.registerElement('super-img', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLImageElement.prototype, {
      createdCallback: function() {
        var caption = this.attributes.getNamedItem('caption').value;
        alert(caption);
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/OMaPIVoV/3/

The createdCallback never fires. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code.

Comment: In the object literal you're passing to `Object.create()`, you are supposed to do `key: value`, not `key = value`.

Comment: DOM elements are [**host** objects](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8), [native objects](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6) belong to ECMAScript.

Comment: I fixed the syntax error, but like it said, that area never even fires so it never gets there.

Comment: How do you know it never fires, did you put a `console.log` inside there? Please also notice that a) you're trying to append a string with `appendChild` which expects DOM nodes, and b) that `<img>` elements must not have any children. Even if your code executes, it should throw.

Comment: Yes, I even put an alert and updated the sample to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you forgot to tell your web component, that it `extends` the native `img` element. Here's a running example based on your fiddle but broken down to the important bits: http://jsbin.com/OMaPIVoV/7/edit

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Object.create(HTMLImageElement.prototype, {
>     createdCallback: function() {…}
> })
> ```

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) does create a map of *property descriptors* as its second parameter - not plain values - like [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) does.

This is also mentioned in [the article you found at "*Adding JS properties and methods*"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#publicapi):

> Of course there are umpteen thousand ways to construct a prototype. If
>   you're not a fan of creating prototypes like this, here's a more
>   condensed version of the same thing:
>
> […] [This] first format allows for the use of ES5 [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).
>   <s>The second allows the use of [get/set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get).</s>

(The strike-through was added by me as it's rubbish)

So what you want is either

```
var SuperImgProto = Object.create(HTMLImageElement.prototype);
SuperImgProto.createdCallback = function() { … };
var SuperImg = document.registerElement('super-img', {prototype: SuperImgProto});
```

or

```
document.registerElement('super-img', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLImageElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {value: function() { … } }
  })
});
```