# Extending JavaScript classes to inherit from HTMLElement

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on trying to make a JavaScript class inherit from  HTMLElement, so that I can create an object of the JavaScript class when document.createElement ("my-custom-elem") is called.

Basically, all I want to do is map the Custom Element to the JavaScript class, so that calls on the object created from the Custom Element would directly call into the JavaScript class members.

I tried all the following with no luck:

```
document.registerElement ('my-custom-element',{prototype:Object.create(CustomElementJSClass.prototype)});

document.registerElement('my-custom-element', {prototype: Object.create(CustomElementJSClass.prototype),extends:'HTMLElement'});
```

I intend to use JavaScript alone and no other add-on libraries, since I don't have that in my environment.

Any help , suggestions much appreciated.
Thanks,
G.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend native DOM elements using "is"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397527/how-to-extend-native-dom-elements-using-is)

Comment: I did read this. The conversation unfortunately does not outline how to actually use the "is" parameter, if that is possible.

Comment: Are you using Polymer?

Comment: You have to pass the "extends" property the name of the **tag**, not the type.  To be general you could extend `<div>` or `<span>`.

Comment: No I am just using a browser with JavaScript. My JavaScript class definition is not mapped to a tag in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

To create a class inherit from HTMLElement and use them as an prototype for an own register custom element, try something like this:

```
function CustomElementJSClass()
{
    this.play = function() { console.log('play'); };
}
CustomElementJSClass.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

document.registerElement('my-custom-element', { prototype: new CustomElementJSClass() });
```

But you can just use one instance for the prototype chain:

```
var proto = new CustomElementJSClass()

document.registerElement('my-custom-element', { prototype: proto });
document.registerElement('my-custom-element-other', { prototype: proto }); // NotSupportedError
```

So it is not possible to trigger a constructor function call, each time the `document.createElement('my-custom-element')` function is called.